# Jenkins permission denied to /usr/share/maven cannot build tests

Tags: java, git, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3

I am running jenkins on AWS.
i am running a pipline through a jenkinsfile

```
node{
stage('Get Git'){
        checkout scm
}
stage('Build'){
    def mvnHome = tool name: 'mvn', type: 'maven'
    sh "${mvnHome} install -DskipTests"

}

stage('Deploy'){
    echo "Deploy code here"
}
```

}

when i run this i get the following errors
(i have left out the git repo stage down below which i working fine)

[image: Jenkins console error]

Answer (score 0):

```
node{
stage('Get Git'){
        checkout scm
}
stage('Build'){
    def mvnHome = tool name: 'mvn', type: 'maven'
    sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn install -DskipTests"

}

stage('Deploy'){
    echo "Deploy code here"
}
}
```

fixed the issue with adding ${mvnHome}/bin/mvn.